# Pypi ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, import, python-module, pypi, python-packaging

**Importing modules work on github but breaks on Pypi**

Allow me to explain, I have a typical file structure resembling the following;

image of directory tree

[image: click link to see image of directory tree]

This works on my computer, some embedded print statements show all my modules executing without error;

```
main core is running
home: OK
filesystem: OK
temporary: OK
inputs: OK
central: OK
output: OK
robotHome: OK
network: OK
external: OK
```

I have uploaded the code to Pypi, Now when I install my pip package
and try to use it in a test script;
(All my code is supposed to do at this point is import modules and print 'ok')

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shenko
print("something")
```

It throws the following error;

```
ImportError: No module named S01_HOME.HOME
```

I have tried using empty **init**.py files, currently it has;

```
from HOME import home
```

If you want to view the source code;
[Click here to see github page](https://github.com/shenko/shenko)

(you can clone the github and run it, then pip install shenko and see if this issue gets reproduced???)

Thank you for your time,
www.shenko.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!**

Basicly the sub-package wasn't being built because python didn't see them. I fixed this simply by adding my sub-packages to my setup.py like so;

```
    packages=find_packages(include=['shenko',
    'shenko.S01_HOME',
    'shenko.S02_FILESYSTEM',
    'shenko.S03_TEMPORARY',
    'shenko.S04_INPUTS',
    'shenko.S05_CENTRAL',
    'shenko.S06_OUTPUT',
    'shenko.S07_ROBOT_HOME',
    'shenko.S08_NETWORK',
    'shenko.S09_EXTERNAL',
    ]),
```

You can view this code on my githubpage here; [Github.com/shenko/shenko](https://github.com/shenko/shenko)

And please feel free to check out my project at `http://www.shenko.org/`
where we hope to create a open source game using panda3d sometime in the near future.

Thanks